# switchMap is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have followed tutorial Angular Tour of Heroes and some other, now I'm trying to build apps with Angular 2. Basically when we're listening to change with Subject, we can wait for some seconds so that request won't burden the network.

Here is my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import {Employee} from "../employee";

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeSearchService {

  private getPersonalURL:string = 'api/employee';   // I'm using mock, btw

  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  search(term:string): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return this.http.get(`api/employee/?firstName=${term}`)
      .map(response =>  response.json().data as Employee[])
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  searchEmployees(term: Observable<string>): Observable<Employee[]> {
    return term.debounceTime(200)
       .distinctUntilChanged()
       .switchMap(term => this.search(term)); // here is the error
  }

  private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('Error on EmployeeSearchService', error);
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }

}
```

And this is the calling component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from "rxjs/Subject";
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';
import { Employee } from '../employee'
import {EmployeeSharedService} from "../employee-shared.service";
import {EmployeeSearchService} from "../employee-search/employee-search.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'employee-list',
  providers: [ EmployeeService ],
  templateUrl: './employee-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-list.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  employees: Employee[];
  selectedEmployee: Employee;
  sortAsc: boolean;

  searchQuery = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private employeeService:EmployeeService, private employeeSearchService:EmployeeSearchService, private employeeSharedService:EmployeeSharedService) {
    this.sortAsc = true;

  }

  ngOnInit() {    // called from here
    this.employeeSearchService.searchEmployees(this.searchQuery)
        .subscribe(result => {
          this.employees = result;
          if(!result) {
            this.getAllEmployees();
          }
        });
  }

  getAllEmployees(): void {
      // calling get all in service
  }

}
```

There are error that says

```
TypeError: term.debounceTime(...).distinctUntilChanged(...).switchMap is not a function
```

Am I missing something, like import or other thing? Because exact code and import are same as Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial, and mine works. But this one isn't.

Comment: And how are you calling that method?

Comment: Right. Please see my edit @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the culprit
`searchQuery = new Subject<string>();`

A `Subject` is **not** an observable, but your function is asking for one, so modify it like this

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.employeeSearchService.searchEmployees(this.searchQuery.asObservable())...
}
```

Comment: Whoa, so I'm misleaded by one of article that said "Subject basically is Observable". I'm accept your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is in a sence like an observable because you can subscribe to it and push data to anything that have subscribed, it **does not** offer the operators that Rx does, hence **not an Rx observable**

Answer (score 24):

You also need to add the `switchMap` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However it still showing the same error.

Comment: Guess you should rebuild your project or something, because this seems like the only reason you would get that error :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import it from rxjs sth like:

> import { switchMap } from 'rxjs';

but it was not highlighted as used so I referenced it explicitly in the code like this:

> return this.user$
> .**rxjs.switchMap**((user: firebase.User) => this.userService.get(user.uid));